# Javascript/Vue.js 2.5х. Ошибка: Свойство или метод не определены в экземпляре, но указаны во время рендеринга?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, table, index

Контекстное меню, отображается при клике правой кнопки мыши на каждой из строк таблицы

**вот так:**

```
                <tbody id="cashtable">
                <tr v-for="(entry, idx) in cashVisit" @contextmenu.prevent="openMenu" :rowid="idx" :id="entry.ID">
                <td v-for="key in columnsСashvisit" :class="{ hidden: ((key == 'ID'))}">
                    {{entry[key]}}
                </td>

              <ul :id="idx" class="rclmenu" tabindex="-1" v-show="viewMenu" tabindex="-1" ref="right" @blur="closeMenu" :style="{top:top, left:left}" >
                    <li @click="deleteCashRow(idx)">Удалить запись</li>
                    <li @click="printCashDirection(idx)">Печать </li>
                    <li @click="printCashСontract(idx)">Печать </li>
                    <li @click="printCashDiscount(idx)">Печать </li>
              </ul>

                </tr>
            </tbody>
```

Но при такой записи в ul :id="idx" я получаю ошибку Vue.js такую:

> Property or method "idx" is not defined on the instance but
>   referenced during render.

Вопросы:

1. Почему я получаю такую ошибку?? ведь я объявил меню внутри tr где
   есть v-for.. а в самой tr где :rowid="idx" это нормально работает..
2. Как тогда по-другому сделать? чтобы передавать index строки в методы
   при клике на пунктах меню..

P.s. Нужно более просторе решение без всяких левых плагинов, jquery и прочего.

Comment: Когда у Вас просят помощи, а в качестве основы дают кривой, с отвратным форматированием код (сложно красиво подать при создании вопроса? Отступы там сделать правильно, например), где видно что автор вот ну ни разу не знает как правильно, у Вас много возникает желания помочь? Укажите версию `Vue`, на 2.5 без ошибок.

Comment: Неее, кажется Я понял - нельзя вставить в tr другие тэги кроме td
Тогда надо сделать следующее::
1) При клике на строке метод OpenMenu получает индекс строки
2) генерит динамически template меню, подставляя индекс(заменяет старое) и рендрит
3) затем отображается перерендренное меню.. Вот как-то так надо это  реализовать.осталось..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нельзя вставить в tr другие тэги кроме td Тогда надо сделать следующее::

1. При клике на строке метод OpenMenu получает индекс строки
2. генерит динамически template меню, подставляя индекс(заменяет старое) и рендрит
3. затем отображается перерендренное меню..

Вот как-то так надо это реализовать.осталось..